# Write a script that takes a Directory as argument and lists all the filenames With the given letters

Tags: bash

My script is going to list all files that contains "z", "x" or " "(blank space) within the given directory. Im new to bashscripting so it is logical for me to think i should go with search operands such as *:

*z* ,  *x* , * *

does anyone know the command? maybe im on the wrong track
ask for clarity and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command as follows:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*[zx ]*"
```

This matches all files in `/path/to/dir` that contain a `z`, `x`, or white space `' '`.

Hence, your script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="$1"

find "$directory" -type f -name "*[zx ]*"
```

Usage: ./script path_to_directory

---

You may want to take a look at the following for more information:

- [How To Use Find and Locate to Search for Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-find-and-locate-to-search-for-files-on-a-linux-vps)
- [Find man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)
- [How to use find with filenames containing spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/how-do-i-use-find-when-the-filename-contains-spaces)